# Influence of cardinal characteristics on nonstandard analysis?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, nonstandard-analysis, ultrapowers, cardinal-characteristics

As I understand, nonstandard analysis usually proceeds by taking a ultrapower of the universe by some nonprincipal ultrafilter on $\mathbb N$. There are continuum many “integers” of this model, but the more specific combinatorics may vary. What if the value of the dominating number $\frak d$ and the bounding number $\frak b$ are small—-does this have any effect on nonstandard analysis?

Comment: Maybe related (but maybe not?): https://mathoverflow.net/questions/230942/bounding-and-dominating-numbers-frak-b-frak-d-via-ultrafilters/230971#230971