# getting one tower from two (stronger hypothesis than a previous question with same title)

Tags: set-theory, order-theory, lattice-theory

Suppose that $(L,\leq_L,0,1)$ is a Boolean algebra that is *dense* as an order (i.e. if $a<_L b\in L$ then there exists $x\in L$, s.t. $a<_L x<_L b$) s.t all non trivial closed segments are isomorphic (as ordered sets with the induced order)

Suppose that there exists $U,V\subset L\setminus \left\{0\right\}$ s.t.

1)$(U,\leq_L)$ and $(V,\leq_L)$ are total ordered set

2)$\inf (U\cup V)=0$

3)$\forall a,b\in U\cup V,\, \inf (a,b)\ne 0$

4)$|U|$ and $|V|$ are regular cardinals

> Does there exists $T\subset L\setminus \left\{0\right\}$  totally ordered by $\leq_L$, s.t. $\inf T=0$ and $|T|\leq |U\cup V|$

Motivation :
This is a particular case of the question : [getting one tower from two](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/299204/getting-one-tower-from-two)
that has been very nicely answered by Joel David Hamkins (the answer is "no" in the general case). I just add here the condition that all non trivial closed segment  $[a,b]\subset L$ are isomorphic (to $L$).